# Compare values in two lists, then tally which list was bigger

Tags: python, list, compare

Absolute beginner here, and first question posted on this forum

I have two lists, A and B. I need to compare their values one by one and see which is bigger.

```
list_A = [10, 11, 13, 30, 22, 11, 10, 33, 22, 22]
list_B = [23, 66, 12, 43, 12, 10, 44, 23, 12, 17]
```

On the first pair (10/23) list B is bigger. Then I want to tally +1 for a variable called B_bigger, and vice versa, +1 for A if the value in A list is bigger.

The result should be:

```
A_bigger = 6

B_bigger = 4
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you will need to zip those lists.
For example:

```
A_bigger = 0
B_bigger = 0

for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B):
    if a > b:
        A_bigger += 1
    if b > a:
        B_bigger += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked great. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `zip` along with a list comprehension over the two input lists to generate a boolean list for greater/less than.  Then, sum each of those lists to generate the counts you want to see:

```
A_bigger = sum([i > j for i, j in zip(list_A, list_B)])
B_bigger = len(list_A) - A_bigger
print("A_bigger = " + str(A_bigger))
print("B_bigger = " + str(B_bigger))
```

This prints:

```
A_bigger = 6
B_bigger = 4
```

**Data:**

```
list_A = [10, 11, 13, 30, 22, 11, 10, 33, 22, 22]
list_B = [23, 66, 12, 43, 12, 10, 44, 23, 12, 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a_big = 0
b_big = 0
for x,y in zip(list_A,list_B):
  if x > y:
    a_big += 1
  if y > x:
    b_big += 1

print("A_Bigger:",a_big)
print("B_Bigger:",b_big)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has already given a good version of `zip`, so here's one using `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

list_A = [10, 11, 13, 30, 22, 11, 10, 33, 22, 22]
list_B = [23, 66, 12, 43, 12, 10, 44, 23, 12, 17]

a = np.array(list_A)
b = np.array(list_B)

# Find a difference between the two lists
diff = a - b

# Compare to see how many result in a positive/negative difference
# anything >0 will be because A is greater, anything <0 is because B is greater
# anything ==0 is because the values are the same 
a_greater = sum(diff > 0)  # 6
b_greater = sum(diff < 0)  # 4
```

Comment: Wow, that's definitelly out of my depth, but I'll remember it! thanks a lot for taking the time